# What is the "perturbation operator" referred to here?

Tags: probability, simplex

Here's an excerpt from [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.08741.pdf) paper:
[image]

I can't get access to the book the citation references. Does anyone know what this operator might be?

$\mathbf{p}$ is the joint pmf of two Bernoulli rvs:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{00} & p_{01}\\
p_{10} & p_{11}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

The transformation labeled 5.4 is:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\Phi \cdot \mathbf{p} \cdot \Psi}{\lVert \Phi \cdot \mathbf{p} \cdot \Psi \rVert_1}
\end{equation*}
where $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are defined as:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & \phi
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & \psi
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

So the transformation is just to rescale one of the marginals, then re-normalize the distribution.

Comment: A perturbation is typically some small change that gives you an approximation near a point. I would expect it to be something close to the identity operator in a meaningful way.

Comment: See https://bookstore.ams.org/conm-287/15 and http://www.leg.ufpr.br/lib/exe/fetch.php/pessoais%3Aabtmartins%3Aa_concise_guide_to_compositional_data_analysis.pdf#page=23